# Question about Computability

Tags: computability, fixed-point-theorems

Q:Suppose $U(n,x)$ is Gödel Universal Function, show that there is $n$ such that $U(n,x)=n+x$ for all $x$
I did some proof but I am mot sure if I am right. 
Let's consider a computable binary function $V(n,x)=n+x$
By theorem, there has to exist a number $n$ such that $U(n,x)=V(n,x)$.
Therefore, there exist n such that $U(n,x)=n+x$.
I am not quite sure this proof is right or not. If it is not correct, could anyone give me some hit for it? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if you used the tag 'fixed-point-theorems' or if it was added by someone else, but that's the key. What do you know about the recursion (aka fixed point) theorem?

Comment: And I don't think your proof is quite right. You say "By theorem, there has to exists..." Which theorem?

Comment: Hi, I know I should use fix point theorem to do this problem, but I just do not know how to use the theorem to get it. The theorem I mentioned is " U(n,x) is Gödel universal function. Let V(n,x) be an bitrary computable function. Then there exists a number p such that U(p,n)=V(p,n)"

Comment: On my book, the fixed point theorem is "Let U be a Gödel universal function and let h be an arbitrary unary total function. Then there exists a number n such that               U(n,x)=U(h(n),x). I can understand the theorem word by word. I just do not know how to use it to get the problem.

Comment: So based on the statement of the fixed point theorem you gave, you just need to find a total computable $h$ such that $U(h(n),x)=n+x$. This is probably done via the SMN theorem.